# How do I get a mohawk or a different hairstyle in Terraria?

Tags: terraria

I bought Terraria a few days ago and I saw people with mohawks and an afro. Now I was wondering how I could get the same?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As of the latest version of Terraria on the PC, it is now possible to change your hairstyle in-game through the [Stylist NPC](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Stylist) who was introduced in 1.2.3.

The Stylist, like the Goblin Tinkerer and the Angler, must be found and freed before she can provide her service. She can be found in the Spider Nest mini biome, found in worlds generated in version 1.2 and above.

For the cost of 1 [image: gold coin] she will give you a hairstyle that could have been chosen at character creation, and for 5 [image: gold coins] she will give you a hairstyle that is exclusive to her. In addition, she can change your hair color for 1 [image: gold coin] and sells [special hair dyes](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hair_Dye) that have a wide variety of interesting effects for 5 - 15 [image: gold coins].

Answer (score 9):

On the character creation menu, click 'Hair'. Above the Hair Colour sliders is 'Hair 1'. Clicking that iterates through a number (15 or so) of different hair styles.

Comment: dang, so i need to create another character?

Comment: Afraid so, as far as I can see. You may be able to edit your file somehow.

Comment: but won't i become a cheater if i do so?

Comment: I don't know, I am afraid..I haven't explored all this stuff yet. All I can gurantee is that you'll be able to change it. (I wouldn't recommend it; anyway, after you get a helmet you'll never see your hair again)

Comment: use Terraria InvEdit, and no, you aren’t a cheater if you don’t actally use it to cheat. Tools are tools. If somebody uses a hammer, he’s no murderer, just because there were murders executed with hammers.

Comment: 19 new hairstyles were added in the Terraria 1.0.6 update, so now there are 36 different hairstyles to choose from. You can now clycle through the hairstyles backwards by right-clicking on the hair selection screen when creating a new character.

Comment: @Commandhat Please don't edit posts in a way that changes their meaning. That is not what edits are for.

Comment: How exactly am I changing the meaning? I added additional methods of changing your hairstyle to receive "a different hairstyle in terraria". Emphasis on "different": people may be googling how to *change* their hairstyle, or get one that is *a different hairstyle* then the one that is already on their character. You can already see OP in the comments above asking how to change their hairstyle exactly like I explained in my edit, so if you want to edit anything edit the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy a wig from the Clothier. 
After defeating skeletor the clothier (old man) should be selling you suit and wig. 
http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Clothier